# define root folder going wrong when config file placed out of root folder

Tags: php, apache, xampp

In my config.php I defined the root folder as

```
define('ROOT_DIR', str_replace('\\', '/', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '../')) . '/');
```

which is

> c:/xampp/htdocs/myWebsite/

For security purpose I moved my config.php file outside the root and placed it on a folder config.

The problem is, now the root_dir which was earlier

> c:/xampp/htdocs/myWebsite

becomes

> c:/xampp/htdocs/config /

How do I keep the config.php where it is now (after moving it away from the root) and yet have the root folder be/shown as

> c:/xampp/htdocs/myWebsite/

Comment: Well you have to change the code in the config.php file!

Comment: @RiggsFolly, you have ? mark. Its confusing. Are you asking me whether I changed my config.php or you suggesting I should change?.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, yeah I have to but am unable to think of or find any solutions. Can you help/suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of hit and try I finally used this code of line to define my ROOT DIR this way

> > define('ROOT_DIR', str_replace('\', '/', realpath(dirname(**FILE**) . '/../')).'/public_html/', false );

it seems to be working fine on a live server.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works:

```
define('ROOT_DIR',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/myWebsite/");
```

Comment: your code above has this result "C:/xampp/htdocs". I am looking for "c:/xampp/htdocs/myWebsite/".

Comment: Yeah, it returns the root directory. Try the updated code. You need to simply use the project directory name after $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . In live server, i.e. in cPanel, this will return home directory (Public HTML)

Comment: and how do I get '/myWebsite/' after I change your suggestion?

Comment: Sorry for the typo... Echoing ROOT_DIR will return c:/xampp/htdocs/myWebsite/

Comment: The path will not change regardless of wherever you keep your config.php file

Comment: change this "myWebsite/" to "/mywebsite/".

Comment: Oh sorry, in WAMP, the path was correct. Check the updated answer now